# How to get the current SharePoint client context site?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model

i am using C# windows application. i want to access the SharePoint site to client Om. Normally we are using, 
   ClientContext objContext = new ClientContext("//Sharepointsite");

but my question is How to get the current SharePoint client context? not using SharePoint site directly.

Comment: How will you get the site reference if you don't provide URL. You can do it using javascript but not using C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can use
objContext = new ClientContext.current; 
property to get your current required object.

Comment: objContext = new ClientContext.current; this line is not accept in windows application.

Comment: ClientContext objContext = new ClientContext().Current

Comment: this line also not accept

Comment: There is no context in a Windows Application. Your only option is to pass the site or web URL to the ClientContext constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a context in a Windows App using CSOM, you still need to create a context. In C#  with CSOM, you'd use:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

ClientContext cc = new ClientContext(Settings.Default.SiteName);
cc.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
string username = Settings.Default.UserName;
string password = Settings.Default.Password;
string domain = Settings.Default.Domain;
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
cc.Credentials = credentials;

//Get a reference to the Web
Web web = cc.Web;
//pass a parameter to get a list...
List sourceList = web.Lists.GetByTitle(list);
cc.Load<List>(sourceList);

//...or hardcode the list name...
List products = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Items");
cc.Load<List>(products);
```

If don't get a context this way, you don't have a Context, Site or Web to reference with the CSOM nor the actual data.

You can use REST to access the data, but you still end up having to reference the site.

One more note: as a Windows App, not using CSOM, if you attempt to use the client Object model you will get a NULL for SPContext if you try to read it directly...because once again, you don't HAVE a Context, so you get a null.